# Pandas read from csv and write back. Floats saving differing values

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas for Python, i'm reading the following from a CSV file:

`2007-03-30 16:34:15.778000,1.96805,1.968,2.4,0.8`

using

```
 df = pd.read_csv(txtFileName, parse_dates=('datetime'), index_col=0, header=None,
                   names=[ 'datetime','bid', 'ask', 'bidvolume', 'askvolume'])
```

`df.dtypes` gives;

```
bid          float64
ask          float64
bidvolume    float64
askvolume    float64
dtype: object
```

I then write the data out to another csv using

`df.to_csv(txtFileName2,header=False)`

The line shows as;

`2007-03-30 16:34:15.778000,1.96805,1.9680000000000002,2.4,0.8`

I understand that this happens due to the way floats work.

What datatypes should I use to prevent this?

`bid` and `ask` are needed to 5 decimal places

`bidVolume` and `askVolume` are needed to 1 decimal place

Comment: If you're not limited to using CSV then why not save your data in HDF5 format and bypass this issue entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `float_format` parameter to format your float values as you like. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Exaple:

```
df.to_csv('your_file', float_format='%.4f')
```